# C++ less operator uses conversion operator

Tags: c++

I cannot understand why for the following dummy class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    operator double() const {
        return 3.14;
    }
};
```

when I try to compare the instances:

```
Foo f1;
Foo f2;

auto res = f1 < f2;
```

the less operator uses the existing

> operator double() const

when comparing values. Where can I find the rules for this behaviour?

Comment: Are you looking for this?
 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: [The C++ standard is where one finds the rules.](http://eel.is/c++draft/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compiler "wants" to make your `<` request work.

There is no `operator<` for `Foo`, but it sees that there is a way to convert `Foo` to `double`. With that, via *implicit conversions*, your comparison will be able to succeed.

If the operator were marked [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) (C++11 or newer), this implicit conversion would be impossible and the compiler would have to give up with your `<` request.

The rules for selecting a function during a call are extremely complicated, so if I were you I would just trust that it works rather than attempting to parse the standard wording. :)

Comment: I think a word about making the operator explicit is in order. If, of course, the OP wants to prevent this from happening, at the cost of implicit conversions.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Good idea.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comments, the compiler is allowed to make 1 user-defined conversion as it's doing here. It sees that it can convert both objects to `double` and `double` does have  `operator <`, so it does that. If you only want to use your conversion operator when you (the programmer) ask for it you can add `explicit`:

```
explicit operator double() const {
    return 3.14;
}
```

Now, the compiler may only call it when you explicitly cast it to such a type:

```
Foo f1;
double d = (double)f1; // conversion operator
```